# Prove that the equations of common tangents to the two hyperbolas $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=1$ are

Tags: conic-sections

Prove that the equations of common tangents to the two hyperbolas $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=1$ are $y=x+\sqrt{a^2-b^2},y=x-\sqrt{a^2-b^2},y=-x+\sqrt{a^2-b^2},y=-x-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

---

I tried to solve the two equations and find the points of intersections of the hyperbolas but these hyperbolas do not intersect each other.
Let the point of tangency be $(x_1,y_1)$ on the $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ on the $\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=1$
For $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$

For $\frac{y^2}{a^2}-\frac{x^2}{b^2}=1$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a^2x}{b^2y}$
$\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}=\frac{a^2x_2}{b^2y_2}$

$b^4x_1y_2=a^4x_2y_1$
I do not know how to take it further.

Comment: HINT: Let $y=mx+c$ be common tangent. Use condition for common tangent for both the curves. Then you will get both $m$ and $c$ in one shot.

Comment: I should add that the equations only have common tangents if $a>b$.

Comment: See  $\#29.b$ of https://goo.gl/g7apIK

Comment: Curves do not need to intersect to have a common tangent...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Implicitly differentiate each, then set the derivatives equal to one another.

Answer (score 0):

[Intersecting the dual conics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428815/the-common-tangent-of-two-tilted-parabolas/2429158#2429158) is one way to go.

The dual conics are $$a^2X^2-b^2Y^2=1\quad (I)$$ and $$-b^2X^2+a^2Y^2=1\quad(II).$$ $b^2(I)+a^2(II)$ gives $(-b^4+a^4)Y^2=b^2+a^2$ or $(a^2-b^2)Y^2=1$. Substituting back to get the corresponding $X$s, we get the four intersection points to be $(X,Y)=(\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}},\pm\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}})$ and $(X,Y)=(-\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}},\pm\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}})$.

The four common tangents are $$Xx+Yy+1=0.$$